# Queue: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, queue

I have the code in main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "queue.h"

int main() {
    Queue Q = CreateQueue();
    /* other code */
    return 0;
}
```

And the `Queue` is defined in `queue.h` as:

```
#ifndef _queue_h

typedef struct QueueRecord * Queue;
struct QueueRecord {
    int Front, Rear;
    int * Array;
};

/* other function declarations */
Queue CreateQueque(); // <--- The Typo.

#endif
```

And function `CreateQueue()` is in file `queue.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "queue.h"

// CREATE THE QUEUE
Queue CreateQueue() {
    Queue Q = malloc(sizeof(struct QueueRecord));
    Q->Array = malloc(sizeof(int*) * MAX_SIZE);
    InitQueue(Q);
    return Q; /* Above goes right except cannot return the pointer. */
}

// INIT THE QUEUE
void InitQueue(Queue Q) {
    Q->Front = -1;
    Q->Rear = -1;
} /* this function does not make an error I think */
```

How could this be fixed? More Error Message was aborted:

```
double free or corruption (out): 0x00619270
```

Thanks.

Comment: That error means that you're doing somthing like this: ``int value = 10; int* value_ptr = value`` instead of ``int * value_ptr = &value``. It doesn't look like it's in that block though, what does ``InitQueue`` do?

Comment: On which line do you get "pointer from integer without a cast"?  And are you compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`?  If not, you should be.

Comment: Have you declared `CreateQueue()` before you use it in `Queue Q = CreateQueue();` because if you haven't, the compiler will assume it returns an `int` (unless you compile in strict C99 or C11 mode) and then trigger the complaint in your subject line.

Comment: @aruisdante `InitQueue()` just set `Q->Front` and `Q->Rear` to `-1`, but I didn't trace error occur here. @John Zwinck The error reports exactly on the line I call `Q = CreateQueue()`, and inner the `CreateQueue` on the line of `return`. Seems confusing.

Comment: Then the problem is likely what @JonathanLeffler suggests. The ``double free`` is happening because you're then trying to ``free`` a locally-scoped ``int``, rather than a pointer to a malloc'd ``QueueRecrord``

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I included it in a header file. And I think it's not (tested the idea).

Comment: This probably warrants an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) to make clear.

Comment: Did you include the header file?  It is not sufficient that the declaration is in the header file (though it is a good idea for it to be in the header!) — the header has to be included in the translation unit (TU) to have any effect.  Have a look at the preprocessed code and see whether `CreateQueue` is actually declared before it is used.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can I paste the complete code in a minute? Thank you.

Comment: Please paste the minimum code necessary to reproduce the problem, but make sure what you paste is compilable apart from this mysterious problem.  See SSCCE (mentioned by Paul) and MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it is here. Compilable, and minimum. Error occurs on line `Queue Q = CreateQueue();`

Comment: @Anonymous it passed...why didn't I get error report if I didn't declare the function?

Comment: As an aside, you also have `#ifndef _queue_h` but no corresponding `#define _queue_h`, which is going to cause you problems if that header ever gets `#include`d twice in the same translation unit.

Comment: It's not an error in C to not declare functions. You can usually pass an argument to your compiler to tell it to make it an error. -Wimplicit for gcc.

Comment: @Anonymous: I rolled it back so the answer continues to make sense, but I'm inclined to agree with you.

Comment: @anonymous: if you are coding in C99 or C11, all functions have to be declared or defined before use. Only C89 is sloppier.  Unfortunately, compilers tend to allow C89 semantics by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your declaration: you've declared "CreateQueque" rather than "CreateQueue". C defaults to an int return type for CreateQueue which is probably what's causing your problem.